# Why doesn't the java compiler recognise fields have been initialized?

Tags: java, variables, compiler-errors, variable-initialization, javacompiler

Suppose I have the following piece of code

```
int myVar;
final boolean condition = <someCondition>;
if (condition) {
   myVar = 1;
}
if (condition) {
   System.out.println("myVar = " + myVar);
}
```

When I compiled this, I got the expected `myVar might not have been initialized` error. 
Is this a bug in the compiler? It's easy to see that "myVar" was set when `condition` is true, and it is only referenced when `condition` is true. (`condition` is also never reset)

P.S: To those comments on me needing to init it to 0, yes I am aware of that. But the point is, I wanted "myVar" to be final (ie., value set at most once)

Comment: @imk It's fairly obvious the OP already knows that, since the whole point of the question is about *why* the compiler is requiring the initialization.

Comment: The Java compiler simply does not do a deep enough analysis to conclude that a value is always assigned to variable `myVar` before it is used.  In general, it does not attempt to correlate the conditions in different conditional statements.

Comment: I don't think the compiler is aware that condition won't change. Take, for example, this being run on a CPU that is interrupted. Condition might  change when it goes back to executing this.

Never mind, I didn't look at the declaration of condition. What @JohnBollinger seems sufficient enough.

Comment: Intrigued I tried this specific scenario out and it compiled and runs with no problems using javac in jdk1.8.0_141.

Comment: @d.j.brown That's because you assigned the compile-time constant `true` to `condition`. If you initialize it with a runtime value, it will fail.

Comment: @erickson yes that is true, now I see the issue in question. Interesting observation, but in practice is this likely to be worth enhancing the compiler for? I'd say no.

Answer (score 4):

The initialization requirement is a formal part of Java, as described in the JLS:

> **For every access of a local variable or blank final field x, x must be definitely assigned before the access, or a compile-time error occurs.**

([JLS 8, chapter 16](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-16.html); emphasis in the original)

The JLS goes on to say

> The analysis takes into account the structure of statements and
>   expressions; it also provides a special treatment of the expression
>   operators `!`, `&&`, `||`, and `? :`, and of boolean-valued constant
>   expressions.
>
> Except for the special treatment of the conditional boolean operators
>   `&&`, `||`, and `? :` and of boolean-valued constant expressions, ***the values
>   of expressions are not taken into account in the flow analysis***.

(emphasis added)

Note well that `condition` being `final` does not make it a "constant expression" as the specification defines that term.  The specification goes on to give [the specific rule for `if` statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-16.html#jls-16.2.7):

> `V` is [un]assigned after `if (e) S` iff `V` is [un]assigned after `S` and `V` is [un]assigned after `e` when [`e` evaluates to] `false`.

In your particular code, then:

> ```
> int myVar;
> ```

`myVar` is definitely *un*assigned here.

> ```
> final boolean condition = <someCondition>;
> if (condition) {
>    myVar = 1;
> }
> ```

`myVar` is "assigned after S" because S, the body of the `if` statement, performs an unconditional assignment.  `myVar` is *not* assigned after evaluation of the condition, however, whether the condition evaluates to `true` or `false`.  Therefore, `myVar` is not definitely assigned at this point in the method.

> ```
> if (condition) {
> ```

And nothing has changed at this point: `myVar` still is not definitely assigned as far as the JLS rules are concerned, so its value must not be read.  The compiler is therefore obligated to report an error in the next statement:

> ```
>    System.out.println("myVar = " + myVar);
> }
> ```